# Is it a TypeScript antipattern to dynamically call a member function stored in a literal?

Tags: typescript

In my Angular component class I have the following pattern used to handle events:

```
private keyHandlers = {
  'ArrowDown': function ($event) {
    this.handleArrowDown($event);
  },

  'ArrowUp': function ($event) {
    this.handleArrowUp($event);
  },
};
```

and then a `@HostListener` like so:

```
@HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown($event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (typeof this.kbdHandlers[$event.code] === 'function') {
      this.keyHandlers[$event.code]($event);
    }
  }
```

Then, further down I have those individual handlers specified as private members of the class:

```
private handleArrowDown($event) {
  // ...
}

private handleArrowUp($event) {
    // ...
}
```

The `"noUnusedLocals": true,` rule however doesn't seem to like it, complaining about handleArrow* methods never used. So my question is - is this kind of approach considered to be an antipatter in TypeScript, or is there a way to satisfy the compiler and notice these members?

Comment: What is the scope of `this` in the keyHandlers functions? Same as handle*() ?

Comment: Yes, it is the same

Comment: How come your keyHandlers funs don't pass down the $event although you expect it?

Comment: You miss my point. It is not about runtime (like passing events, or even using `.bind`), it is rather about compilation.

Comment: I did NOT miss your point and it had nothing to do with runtime. I was asking a simple question: why do you keep an unused variable? - `function ($event) {this.handleArrowDown();}` It wouldn't be the first time that a meta tool trips on seemingly unrelated details.

Comment: I wrote this code in my post not caring about the details. My point is the general pattern, ie. keeping the handlers in a literal object, rather than capturing the parameters or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes and no.

TypeScript does not encourage dynamic reference as it can't analyze your code and detect such usage. So, unfortunately, it will complain in this case.

It has the good intent to help you, but it is not doing the right thing. Or put in another way, it does not have sufficient knowledge to do the right thing.

On the other hand, it definitely should not "prohibit" such usage because TypeScript is JavaScript. Thus there should be a way to mitigate this situation.

In fact, it is in a discussion: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9448

For now, I would recommend turning `noUnusedLocals` off (I know, that hurts. And it hurts either way).

Pointed out by @jmlopez, here are two alternative solutions:

```
export class SomeComponent {
  private keyHandlers = {
    // Specifying `this` will be processed by the compiler to make the function as used.
    'ArrowDown': function (this: SomeComponent, $event) {
      this.handleArrowDown($event);
    },
    // Arrow function will have the same effect.
    'ArrowUp': ($event) => {
      this.handleArrowUp($event);
    }
  }
  onKeyDown($event) {
    if (typeof this.keyHandlers[$event.code] === 'function') {
      this.keyHandlers[$event.code]($event);
    }
  }
  private handleArrowDown(_event) {
    // ...
  }

  private handleArrowUp(_event) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have actually been trying to refactor my code to use the approach described above, thinking that it would be a nicer way to code. But then I bumped into this problem. Being aware of my limited knowledge of TypeScript (using maybe 50% of its power), I assumed I might have just been caught in trap of my ignorance, like missing out some typecasting. Actually it is no surpise to me TypeScript gets puzzled in this case, and no - I will no give up on noUnusedLocals - I see much more benefit from it than I do from refactoring my event handlers :) Thanks once again.

Comment: @user776686 See my comment on the issue https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9448#issuecomment-321162238, it seems that you have two options on how to deal with the problem you posted.

Comment: Thanks @jmlopez for escalating the question. I often forget to use arrow functions - this might be a solution here. Btw, if you believe my question could and should be rephrased, feel free to edit it :)